# Index on multiple properties in Neo4j / Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can I create an index with multiple properties in cypher?

I mean something like

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(first_name, last_name)
```

If I understand correctly this is not possible, but if I want to write queries like:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.first_name = 'Andres' AND n.last_name = 'Doe'
RETURN n
```

Does these indexes make sense?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(first_name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(last_name)
```

Or should I try to merge "first_name" and "last_name" in one property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indexes are good for defining some key that maps to some value or set of values. The key is always a single dimension.

Consider your example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(first_name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(last_name)
```

These two indexes now map to those people with the same first name, and separately it maps those people with the same last name. So for each person in your database, two indexes are created, one on the first name and one on the last name.

Statistically, this example stinks. Why? Because the distribution is stochastic. You'll be creating a lot of indexes that map to small clusters/groups of people in your database. You'll have a lot of nodes indexed on `JOHN` for the first name. Likewise you'll have a lot of nodes indexed on `SMITH` for the last name.

Now if you want to index the user's full name, then concatenate, forming `JOHN SMITH`. You can then set a property of person as `person.full_name`. While it is redundant, it allows you to do the following:

1. Create

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Person(full_name)
   ```
2. Match

   ```
   MATCH (n:Person)
   USING INDEX n:Person(full_name)
   WHERE n.full_name = 'JOHN SMITH'
   ```

You can always refer to http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ for more tips and guidelines.

Cheers,

Kenny

Comment: but if he wants to run a search only on first or last name? Will have to use regexp? Will it still trade off well, or its better to have separate fields indexing. Asking this cos im thinking how to best index some fields describing place's location - country, city, placename. And search can run on any of those fields.

Comment: What if you have an integer property and a text property?  Suppose you want to search on an integer range and filter on the text property at the same time?   Does the query planner only match against one index, or does it leverage both?

Comment: Is it possible to combine two properties before the data is imported from a csv file?

Answer (score 9):

As of 3.2, Neo4j supports composite indexes. For your example:

`CREATE INDEX ON :Person(first_name, last_name)`

You can read more on composite indexes [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#create-a-composite-index).